# the getChildView method run 2 times in Expandable ListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

i am creating an app which contains an expandable list view. the child views are created dynamically. and it run successfully. During debugging i found that the getChildview function  runs 2 times.

i create dynamic layouts and put it into a list. when the getChildView runs 2 times the layouts added 2 times in to the list..

Answer (score 1):

`getChildView()` is not an appropriate place to create children. It might be called pretty often. The rendering process needs to visit children twice, anyway.

It's not possible to judge where the appropriate place would be for adding children to your list, or even if your list approach is the right way to do it, without much more information.

Comment: @user1882058 I don't like to repeat myself, but here you go: _It's not possible to judge where the appropriate place would be for adding children to your list, or even if your list approach is the right way to do it, without much more information._

Answer (score 0):

If you regenerate the list in group click, then removing it can be a solution. For example, in the following code, the getChildView() always called twice because of myList.expandGroup(groupPosition).

```
public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, long id) {

        //get the group header
        HeaderInfo headerInfo = medicationDate.get(groupPosition);
        myList.expandGroup(groupPosition);
        //set the current group to be selected so that it becomes visible
        //myList.setSelectedGroup(groupPosition);
        //display it or do something with it
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Child on Header " + headerInfo.getHeaderInfo()+"with childsize"+headerInfo.getChildInfo().size(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to android development and maybe wrong, but as I see it `getChildView()` has 4th argument View `convertView` which is null first time view need to be rendered. Once created it is stored and reused again when needed. So if you create new views in `getChildView()` it is enough to have something like this

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  if (convertView != null) {
      // View is already created here, update it if you like
      return convertView;
  }
  // Else create your view(s) here and return the root of view container as usual
  ...
  return convertView; // or whatever your root view is
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The height of the listview should be `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

one thing worked for me was.

```
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // To avoid refreshing return true and makesure Ids each position have same view.
    return true;
    //return false;
}
```